# Get Chatter Topic Limits via Apex

Tags: apex, chatter, governorlimits, topics

I know that the current governor limit allows only 10 topics in single chatter post thread.  Is it possible to get this limit using apex, via the Limits class for example?

This would allow the code to adjust automatically to the new limit if it were ever to change.